# Update same column, same DB with specific records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We are migrating a site from one Active Directory system to another but in the third-party app, we need to keep the old accounts, so we renamed the old accounts with "_Old" appended to the last name. Now we need to update a particular column from the old accounts into the new accounts so that their roles in the app match what they were before the migration.

I've figured out how to do it with one person.  I need to take this same logic and apply it to multiple accounts.

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
Update Staff
Set Role_Id =
    (   SELECT Role_Id 
        FROM Staff 
        where Staff_First_Name = 'Jane' 
            AND Staff_Last_Name = 'Doe_Old')
Where Staff_First_Name = 'Jane'
    AND Staff_Last_Name = 'Doe'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That wiuld only work when you have fixed rules
Like Doe and Doe_Old, so you can link the records.

IF you can't find a rule for the `ON clause`it us impossible and you have to go over every record

Edit: it goes actually easier

> ```
> CREATE tABLE  Staff (Role_Id  INT, Staff_First_Name VARCHAR(10), Staff_Last_Name VARCHAR(10));
> INSERT INTO  Staff VALUES (10, 'Jane' , 'Doe_Old');
>
> INSERT INTO  Staff VALUES (NULL, 'Jane', 'Doe')
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Staff;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Role_Id | Staff_First_Name | Staff_Last_Name
> ------: | :--------------- | :--------------
>      10 | Jane             | Doe_Old        
>    null | Jane             | Doe
> ```

> ```
> Update s1 
> Set Role_Id = s2.Role_Id
> FROM Staff s1 
> JOIN  Staff s2 ON s1.Staff_First_Name = s2.Staff_First_Name
>                         AND s2.Staff_Last_Name = CONCAT(s1.Staff_Last_Name,'_Old')
> GO
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Staff;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Role_Id | Staff_First_Name | Staff_Last_Name
> ------: | :--------------- | :--------------
>      10 | Jane             | Doe_Old        
>      10 | Jane             | Doe
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=88d4a1a1aa4c261db2fdfa2cd42317e6)*

This Version is only necessary if you need some calculation made in th subquery

> ```
> CREATE tABLE  Staff (Role_Id  INT, Staff_First_Name VARCHAR(10), Staff_Last_Name VARCHAR(10));
> INSERT INTO  Staff VALUES (10, 'Jane' , 'Doe_Old');
>
> INSERT INTO  Staff VALUES (NULL, 'Jane', 'Doe')
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Staff;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Role_Id | Staff_First_Name | Staff_Last_Name
> ------: | :--------------- | :--------------
>      10 | Jane             | Doe_Old        
>    null | Jane             | Doe
> ```

> ```
> Update Staff
> Set Role_Id = s2.Role_Id
> FROM Staff s1 
> JOIN
> (SELECT Role_Id,Staff_First_Name,Staff_Last_Name
>         FROM Staff) s2 ON s1.Staff_First_Name = s2.Staff_First_Name
>                         AND s2.Staff_Last_Name = CONCAT(s1.Staff_Last_Name,'_Old')
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Staff;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Role_Id | Staff_First_Name | Staff_Last_Name
> ------: | :--------------- | :--------------
>      10 | Jane             | Doe_Old        
>      10 | Jane             | Doe
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb89cd10774871535b6398aea596a2be)*

Comment: Why do you need a subquery for `s2` it appears to be unnecessary